# bash: substract constant number after prefix

Tags: bash

I have a large text file with many entries like this:

```
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_05485"
```

including the empty spaces in the beginning. Unfortunately, the first identifier does not start with `00001`.

The only part in this line that is changing is the number.

I would like to change the PREFIX (this I can do easily with `sed`), but I also want to decrease the number so it looks like this:

```
                     /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00001"
```

(the next entry should be `..."myNewPrefix_00002"` and so on). Alternatively, the entry could also be without leading zeros.

As far as I know, `sed` cannot calculate (like substracting a constant number). Any ideas how I can solve that?

Thank you very much. If the question is unclear, please let me know and I will try to improve it.

EDIT: Sometimes the same number occurs twice (this should also be the case in the modified file, for instance

```
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_12345"
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_12345"
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_12346"
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_12347"
```

should be in the end

```
                     /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00001"
                     /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00001"
                     /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00002"
                     /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00003"
```

Comment: Use `awk`, or any other language designed for processing arbitrary data.

Comment: Ups, sorry that was unclear, yes it should be there. I will edit the question.

Comment: Sorry, this is not the way StackOverflow works. Questions of the form "I want to do X, please give me tips and/or sample code" are considered off-topic. Please visit the [help] and read [ask], and especially read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `awk`:

```
awk -v pf='myNewPrefix' 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="="}
$1 ~ /\/locus_tag$/ && split($2, a, /_/) == 2 {
   $2 = sprintf("\"%s_%05d\"", pf, (a[2] in seen ? i : ++i)); seen[a[2]]
} 1' file
```

```
                 /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00001"
                 /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00001"
                 /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00002"
                 /locus_tag="myNewPrefix_00003"
```

Comment: Thank you, that is very cool. I have a small problem with my data, however. Sometimes numbers occur twice and so it should be in the new file (see edit in the question). Do you have an idea for that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Check this Perl one liner

```
/tmp> cat littlebird.txt
abcdef
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_12345"
hello hai
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_12345"
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_12346"
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_12347"
123 456
end
/tmp> perl -pe 'BEGIN{$r=qr/PREFIX_(.+)["]/} if(/$r/) {$kv{$1}++;$kv{$1}==1 and $kv2{$1}=sprintf("%04d",++$i) for(keys %kv) } s/$r/PREFIX_$kv2{$1}/g ' littlebird.txt
abcdef
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_0001
hello hai
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_0001
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_0002
                     /locus_tag="PREFIX_0003
123 456
end
/tmp>
```